# Entities POCO with EF, creating relationship with POCO

Tags: entity-framework, poco, model-associations

Hi good day

I hope you can help me, then I explain my problem:

These are my entities:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjZmX.jpg

I need to create with POCO such relationships for example resultadobusquedaofac with SDN, For this I use the POCO templates

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYbzy.jpg

then I myself believe partnerships within these entities:

ResultadoBusquedaOfac

```
public partial class ResultadoBusquedaOfac
{
    #region Primitive Properties

    public virtual int ent_num
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string SDN_Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual int KeyCliente
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string HayCoincidencia
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string HayCoincidenciaAlias
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion

    public virtual ICollection&lt;OFAC_SDN&gt; OFAC_SDN
    {
        get
        {
            if (_oFAC_SDN == null)
            {
                var newCollection = new FixupCollection&lt;OFAC_SDN&gt;();
                newCollection.CollectionChanged += FixupOFAC_SDN;
                _oFAC_SDN = newCollection;
            }
            return _oFAC_SDN;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_oFAC_SDN, value))
            {
                var previousValue = _oFAC_SDN as FixupCollection&lt;OFAC_SDN&gt;;
                if (previousValue != null)
                {
                    previousValue.CollectionChanged -= FixupOFAC_SDN;
                }
                _oFAC_SDN = value;
                var newValue = value as FixupCollection&lt;OFAC_SDN&gt;;
                if (newValue != null)
                {
                    newValue.CollectionChanged += FixupOFAC_SDN;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private ICollection&lt;OFAC_SDN&gt; _oFAC_SDN;</em></strong>


    private void FixupOFAC_SDN(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (OFAC_SDN item in e.NewItems)
            {
                item.ResultadoBusquedaOfac = this;
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (OFAC_SDN item in e.OldItems)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(item.ResultadoBusquedaOfac, this))
                {
                    item.ResultadoBusquedaOfac = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}OFAC_SDN

```
public partial class OFAC_SDN
{
    #region Primitive Properties

   <strong><em> public virtual Nullable&lt;int&gt; id_Ofac
    {
        get { return _id_Ofac; }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                _settingFK = true;
                if (_id_Ofac != value)
                {
                    if (ResultadoBusquedaOfac != null &amp;&amp; ResultadoBusquedaOfac.ent_num != value)
                    {
                        ResultadoBusquedaOfac = null;
                    }
                    _id_Ofac = value;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _settingFK = false;
            }
        }
    }
    private Nullable&lt;int&gt; _id_Ofac;</em></strong>

    public virtual int ent_num
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string SDN_Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string SDN_Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Program
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Call_Sign
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Vess_type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Tonnage
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string GRT
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Vess_flag
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Vess_owner
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Remarks
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion
    #region Navigation Properties

    public virtual ResultadoBusquedaOfac ResultadoBusquedaOfac
    {
        get { return _resultadoBusquedaOfac; }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_resultadoBusquedaOfac, value))
            {
                var previousValue = _resultadoBusquedaOfac;
                _resultadoBusquedaOfac = value;
                FixupResultadoBusquedaOfac(previousValue);
            }
        }
    }
    private ResultadoBusquedaOfac _resultadoBusquedaOfac;</em></strong>

    public virtual ICollection&lt;OFAC_ADD&gt; OFAC_ADD
    {
        get
        {
            if (_oFAC_ADD == null)
            {
                var newCollection = new FixupCollection&lt;OFAC_ADD&gt;();
                newCollection.CollectionChanged += FixupOFAC_ADD;
                _oFAC_ADD = newCollection;
            }
            return _oFAC_ADD;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_oFAC_ADD, value))
            {
                var previousValue = _oFAC_ADD as FixupCollection&lt;OFAC_ADD&gt;;
                if (previousValue != null)
                {
                    previousValue.CollectionChanged -= FixupOFAC_ADD;
                }
                _oFAC_ADD = value;
                var newValue = value as FixupCollection&lt;OFAC_ADD&gt;;
                if (newValue != null)
                {
                    newValue.CollectionChanged += FixupOFAC_ADD;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private ICollection&lt;OFAC_ADD&gt; _oFAC_ADD;

    public virtual ICollection&lt;OFAC_ALT&gt; OFAC_ALT
    {
        get
        {
            if (_oFAC_ALT == null)
            {
                var newCollection = new FixupCollection&lt;OFAC_ALT&gt;();
                newCollection.CollectionChanged += FixupOFAC_ALT;
                _oFAC_ALT = newCollection;
            }
            return _oFAC_ALT;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_oFAC_ALT, value))
            {
                var previousValue = _oFAC_ALT as FixupCollection&lt;OFAC_ALT&gt;;
                if (previousValue != null)
                {
                    previousValue.CollectionChanged -= FixupOFAC_ALT;
                }
                _oFAC_ALT = value;
                var newValue = value as FixupCollection&lt;OFAC_ALT&gt;;
                if (newValue != null)
                {
                    newValue.CollectionChanged += FixupOFAC_ALT;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private ICollection&lt;OFAC_ALT&gt; _oFAC_ALT;

    #endregion

    #region Association Fixup

    private bool _settingFK;

    private void FixupResultadoBusquedaOfac(ResultadoBusquedaOfac previousValue)
    {
        if (previousValue != null &amp;&amp; previousValue.OFAC_SDN.Contains(this))
        {
            previousValue.OFAC_SDN.Remove(this);
        }

        if (ResultadoBusquedaOfac != null)
        {
            if (!ResultadoBusquedaOfac.OFAC_SDN.Contains(this))
            {
                ResultadoBusquedaOfac.OFAC_SDN.Add(this);
            }
            if (id_Ofac != ResultadoBusquedaOfac.ent_num)
            {
                id_Ofac = ResultadoBusquedaOfac.ent_num;
            }
        }
        else if (!_settingFK)
        {
            id_Ofac = null;
        }
     }

    private void FixupOFAC_ADD(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (OFAC_ADD item in e.NewItems)
            {
                item.OFAC_SDN = this;
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (OFAC_ADD item in e.OldItems)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(item.OFAC_SDN, this))
                {
                    item.OFAC_SDN = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void FixupOFAC_ALT(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (OFAC_ALT item in e.NewItems)
            {
                item.OFAC_SDN = this;
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (OFAC_ALT item in e.OldItems)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(item.OFAC_SDN, this))
                {
                    item.OFAC_SDN = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Now when I run the test query:

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
        LegitimacionEntities context = new LegitimacionEntities();
        var query = context.ResultadoBusquedaOfac.Include("OFAC_SDN").Where(us =&gt; us.ent_num.Equals(10)).First();

        MessageBox.Show(query.SDN_Name);
    }
}
```

}

throws me the following error:

A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'LegitimacionModel.ResultadoBusquedaOfac' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'OFAC_SDN'.

And in addition to this then I have to pass the data by dataservice or WCF, right now I'm doing so to prove first that the relations are well before passing it to the above.

Many thanks in advance and I welcome your comments...

happy days

Comment: Is there a relationship between ResultadoBusquedaOfac and OFAC_SDN? I don't see it. If you can modify the database then add foreign key property and then refresh the schema. Navigation property should be added automatically.